Monotonic functions
Let f and h be strictly increasing functions, g a strictly decreasing one
Do the graphs of g and f have only one intersection? Does the same thing happen to the graphs of f and h? f:R→R, g:R→R, h:R →R

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
